# typedef struct declaration gives back an error

Tags: c

I do not understand what is wrong with the following piece of code. I am trying to create a linked list in C. I am creating a typedef struct which I call a person, then I declare a pointer that points to that structure and I am trying to allocate some memory for it to be able to store all its components. The compiler gives back an error saying that 'head' does not name a type.

```
typedef struct node {
    int num;
    struct node *next;
} person;

person *head = NULL;
head = (person*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Comment: You can't include the assignment to `head` at file scope.  If your code is not at file scope, you've not shown us an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: Using different names causes confusion. You should either use `typedef struct node {} node;` or `typedef struct person {} person;`

Comment: @Gerhardh We seem to be of different opinion. Mine is that using the same name for different things is confusing. In this case there is the struct tag `node`, which only in combination with `struct` makes a type. There is also the typedefed type `person`. Using different but noticably related similar names is my favorite. Like the very verbose `struct person_tag` (which can be used within the `struct`) to visibly relate to the type `person` (which cannot). Well, opinions divide; the compiler does not mind either.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the assignment to head is in a function, it is still incorrect as `node` is not a valid type or variable. It's either `struct node` but as you `typedef`'d that you should use `person`

```
head = malloc(sizeof(person));
```

But as the variable `head` is already of type `person*` you can also do

```
head = malloc(sizeof(*head));
```

which has the advantage you no longer need to know the exact type name (should you ever change it)

Also note that casting the result of `malloc` is not needed and unwanted.

You will have to check for the result being NULL though.

Comment: @Yunnosch, very true. I updated the answer.

Comment: :-) Got my upvote now. Feel free to add the discussion of what a struct tag is from my comment.